# How to pass selected index/value from view to controller's action

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a selection box like this:

```html
<select for="SortBy"
    class="border-0"
    asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MarkerSortChoice>()"
    name="SortBy"
    onchange="location.href='@Url.Action("SortMarkers", "Markers", new { currentPage =  @Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage })'">
</select>
```

Along with parameter 'currentPage', I also want to pass selected index or selected value from select to the controller's action.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

The simplest way is to move the `OnChange` to a `script` tag inside a section in your view. Grab the index and value then use the `location.href`.

Something like this:

```js
@model YourModel

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){       
        $("#Sort").change(function () {
            var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected').eq(0);
            var index = selectedOption.val();
            var val = selectedOption.text();
            location.href = `/Markers/SortMarkers?currentPage=@Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage&value=${val}&index=${index}`
        });
    })
</script>
}

//HTML and Razor goes here
```

Comment: it worked, however, we can't put in JS function this part: '@Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage' because this code lives on the server and JS won't recognize it. Do you have a solution that would be more compatible with my original approach?

Comment: @Ivan I am not sure if i understand your comment clearly but the use of `@section` gives you the ability to use C# in your javascript so the `@Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage` will work as expected because the `@section scripts` is placed in your view and not in a separate js file. (See my updated answer)

Comment: ok, I overlloked '@section part'. However, now I get the folowing error: "InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName")."

Comment: @Ivan Before the end of your `body` tag in `Layout.cshtml` and after all your scripts add this `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)`.